# IPFS file upload and view

Tags: ipfs

I uploaded a pdf file to the IPFS de-centralised network. My question here. When I have the IPFS console and I couldn't view the pdf file anymore through the https://ipfs.io/gateway. Why is that? My understanding is once the file is uploaded to the IPFS network and the file will be distributed to the nodes.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a file to IPFS via `ipfs add <file>` does not distribute it to the network (that would be free hosting!), it only puts the file into the standard format (IPLD) and makes it *possible* to access over the network (IPFS) as long as someone connected to the network has the file. When you first add something, that's only you. So if you close your laptop, suddenly the file is no longer available. UNLESS someone else has downloaded it since then, because then they can distribute it while your computer is off. There are many "pinning services" which do just that, for a small fee.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Your understanding is correct,But can you tell me how are you uploading files to ipfs network there are number of ways to add data to ipfs network,

if you are able to add data to ipfs you will get the hash of the data, condition is daemon is running locally so that your data can be broadcasted to other peers you are attached to, you can check it by command: `ipfs swarm peers` 
if above conditions are fulfilled you view/get data from `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/<replace with hash you will get after adding>`

if daemon is not running you can able to add you file and get the hash but you files will be saved locally, you wont be able to access it from web.

please let me know if you need other information